# How to plot Month on the x-axis and Rainfall on the y-axis with Seaborn?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, kaggle

I have a dataset for monthly rainfall in India over a century from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/ravisane1/monthly-rainfall-data-india-of-a-century. I've used melt to convert the months from columns to rows by doing a

```
rain_data_by_month = rain_data.melt(id_vars=["State", "District","Year"], 
        var_name="Month", 
        value_name="Rainfall")
```

Now I'd like to do a plot of the month on the X-axis and Total Rainfall on the Y-axis. So I first did a

```
rdf = rain_data_by_month.groupby(['Month'])['Rainfall'].sum().reset_index()
```

How can I get seaborn to plot rdf the way I've described above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using a [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).
- [kaggle: india_monthly_rainfall_data.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/ravisane1/monthly-rainfall-data-india-of-a-century?select=india_monthly_rainfall_data.csv)
- The API doesn't know how to order the months unless you specify the order.

  - Use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) to order the Month column and use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module to get an ordered `list` of months, or create a `list` manually.
- See [Weather Visualization for Portland, OR: 1940 - 2020](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/Portland_Weather/Portland_Weather.html)
- See [Plot Daily Max & Min Temp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929123) - This could be used for rainfall too.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import calendar

# load data
df = pd.read_csv('data/india_monthly_rainfall_data.csv')

# melt
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=["State", "District","Year"],  var_name="Month",  value_name="Rainfall")

# groupby sum
rdf = dfm.groupby(['Month'])['Rainfall'].sum().reset_index()

# ordered
rdf.Month = pd.Categorical(rdf.Month, categories=list(calendar.month_abbr)[1:], ordered=True)

# display(rdf)
Month     Rainfall
  Apr  2.15743e+06
  Aug  1.52092e+07
  Dec  6.44887e+05
  Feb  9.17824e+05
  Jan  7.38981e+05
  Jul  1.65285e+07
  Jun  1.02515e+07
  Mar  1.17930e+06
  May  4.09921e+06
  Nov  1.56662e+06
  Oct  4.33708e+06
  Sep  1.00620e+07

# plot
p = sns.barplot('Month', 'Rainfall', data=rdf)
p.set_ylabel('Rainfall (mm)')
p.set_title(f'1901 - 2002: Total Cumulative Monthly Rainfall')
```

[image]

Comment: sns.barplot is what I was looking for but thank you for the rest of the code as well - my numbers matched and the graph is what I was looking for. Is there a particularly good resource/link for seaborn usage that you can share? Thanks again Trenton McKinney!

Comment: @raghus glad this solved your question. See [seaborn tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html) and [all SO questions tagged seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seaborn).