# How to make a line plot from a dataframe with multiple categorical columns in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to make line chart for the different categories where one is a different country, and one is a different country for weekly based line charts. Initially, I was able to draft line plots using `seaborn` but it is not quite handy like setting its label, legend, color palette and so on. I am wondering is there any way to easily reshape this data with multiple categorical variables and render line charts. In initial attempt, I tried `seaborn.relplot` but it is not easy to tune its parameter and hard to customize the resulted plot. Can anyone point me to any efficient way to reshape dataframe with multiple categorical columns and render a clear line chart? Any thoughts?

**reproducible data & my attempt**:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/cb0553e009933574ac7ec3109ffb5140/raw/a277bc00dc08e526a7d5b7ead5425905f7206bfa/export.csv'
dff = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
dff.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)

df2_bf = dff.groupby(['destination', 'weekly'])['FCF_Beef'].sum().unstack()
df2_bf = df2_bf.fillna(0)
mm = df2_bf.T
mm.columns.name = None
mm = mm[~(mm.isna().sum(1)/mm.shape[1]).gt(0.9)].fillna(0)

#Total sum per column: 
mm.loc['Total',:]= mm.sum(axis=0)
mm1 = mm.T
mm1 = mm1.nlargest(6, columns=['Total'])
mm1.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
mm2 = mm1.T
mm2.reset_index(inplace=True)
mm2['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(mm2['weekly'])

mm2['year'] = mm2['weekly'].dt.year
mm2['week'] = mm2['weekly'].dt.isocalendar().week
df = mm2.melt(id_vars=['weekly','week','year'], var_name='country')

df_ = df.groupby(['country', 'year', 'week'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
sns.relplot(data=df_, x='week', y='value', hue='year', row='country', kind='line', height=6, aspect=2, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False}, sizes=(20, 10))
```

**current plot**

this is [one of current plot that I made with `seaborn.relplot`](https://ibb.co/xDffSmM)

structure of plot is okay for me, but in `seaborn.replot`, it is hard to tune parameter and it is as flexible as using `matplotlib`. Also, I realized that the way of aggregating my data is not very efficient. I think there might be a shortcut to make the above code snippet more efficient like:

```
plt_data = []
for i in dff.loc[:, ['FCF_Beef','FCF_Beef']]:
    ...
```

but doing this way I faced a couple of issues to make the right plot. Can anyone point me out how to make this simple and efficient in order to make the expected line chart with matplotlib? Does anyone know any better way of doing this? Any idea? Thanks

**desired output**

In my desired plot, first I need to iterate list of countries, where each country has one subplot, in each subplot, x-axis shows 52 weeks and y-axis shows `weeklyExport` amount of different years for each country. Here is [draft plot that I made with `seaborn.relplot`](https://ibb.co/MhQTw5Z).

note that, I don't like the output from `seaborn.relplot`, so I am wondering how can I make above attempt more efficient with `matplotlib` attempt. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As requested by the OP, following is an iterative way to plot the data.
- The following example plots each year, for a given `'destination'` in a single figure
- This is similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64069291/7758804) for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64067519/7758804).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/cb0553e009933574ac7ec3109ffb5140/raw/a277bc00dc08e526a7d5b7ead5425905f7206bfa/export.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'], usecols=range(1, 6))

# groupby destination and iterate through for plotting
for g, d in df.groupby(['destination']):

    # create the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))
    
    # add lines for specific years
    for year in d.weekly.dt.year.unique():
        data = d[d.weekly.dt.year == year].copy()  # select the data from d, by year
        data['week'] = data.weekly.dt.isocalendar().week  # create a week column
        data.sort_values('weekly', inplace=True)
        display(data.head())  # display is for jupyter, if it causes an error, use pring
        data.plot(x='week', y='FCF_Beef', ax=ax, label=year)
    
    plt.show()
```

- Single sample plot

[image]

- If we look at the tail of one of the dataframes, `data.weekly.dt.isocalendar().week` as putting the last day of the year as `week 1`, so a line is drawn back to the last data point being placed at week 1.
- This function rests on `datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31).isocalendar()` and is the expected behavior from the `datetime` module, as per this [closed pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35480).

[image]

- Removing the last row with `.iloc[:-1, :]`, is a work around
- Alternatively, replace `data['week'] = data.weekly.dt.isocalendar().week` with `data['week'] = data.weekly.dt.strftime('%W').astype('int')`

```py
data.iloc[:-1, :].plot(x='week', y='FCF_Beef', ax=ax, label=year)
```

[image]

### Updated with all code from OP

```py
# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/cb0553e009933574ac7ec3109ffb5140/raw/a277bc00dc08e526a7d5b7ead5425905f7206bfa/export.csv'
dff = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'], usecols=range(1, 6))

df2_bf = dff.groupby(['destination', 'weekly'])['FCF_Beef'].sum().unstack()
df2_bf = df2_bf.fillna(0)
mm = df2_bf.T
mm.columns.name = None
mm = mm[~(mm.isna().sum(1)/mm.shape[1]).gt(0.9)].fillna(0)

#Total sum per column: 
mm.loc['Total',:]= mm.sum(axis=0)
mm1 = mm.T
mm1 = mm1.nlargest(6, columns=['Total'])
mm1.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
mm2 = mm1.T
mm2.reset_index(inplace=True)
mm2['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(mm2['weekly'])

mm2['year'] = mm2['weekly'].dt.year
mm2['week'] = mm2['weekly'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('int')
df = mm2.melt(id_vars=['weekly','week','year'], var_name='country')

# groupby destination and iterate through for plotting
for g, d in df.groupby(['country']):

    # create the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))
    
    # add lines for specific years
    for year in d.weekly.dt.year.unique():
        data = d[d.weekly.dt.year == year].copy()  # select the data from d, by year
        data.sort_values('weekly', inplace=True)
        display(data.head())  # display is for jupyter, if it causes an error, use pring
        data.plot(x='week', y='value', ax=ax, label=year, title=g)
    
    plt.show()
```